# render content in regular model view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twilio

I am following twilio tutorial and they have content of a file hello-monkey.cshtml as follows:

```
@{
    // make a list of senders we know, indexed by phone number
    ****var people = new Dictionary<string, string>() { 
        {"+14158675309","Curious George"},
        {"+14158675310","Boots"},
        {"+14158675311","Virgil"},
        {"+14158675312","Marcel"}
    };

    // if the caller is known, then greet them by name
    // otherwise, consider them just another monkey
    string name = "Monkey";
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["From"]))
    {
        name = people[Request["From"]];
    }**

    // now greet the caller
    Response.ContentType = "text/xml";**
}
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Say>Hello @name.</Say>
</Response>
```

and they want us to render the page as http://www.mysite.com/hello-monkey.cshtml...

How can I write this code on the server side.. In the model section so that I could just call the page as http://www.mysite.com/Monkey

In other words is it possible to transfer the bold section code in Model part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "model section", but you can do everything shown above directly in the Controller if you don't want to put it in the View:

```
public class PhoneController : TwilioController  
   public ActionResult Hello() {

      var response = new TwilioResponse();
      response.Say(name);

      return TwiML(response);    
   }
}
```

I'd suggest installing the Twilio.Mvc helper library into your ASp.NET MVC project to get the TwilioController base class.  This lets you use the TwiML helper method shown above to return TwiML commands as your ActionResult.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Devin.. I was googlig today and I did notice the above code. I will try this out at home. Thank you very much for speedy answer.

Comment: I will search the internet to see what other twiml commands are out there like Say, Dial, etc. Thanks

Comment: All of the twiml elements are documented here:  https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml